# setting point sizes when using Gadfly in Julia

Tags: graphics, point, diagram, julia, gadfly

In my attempts to practice Julia, I've made a program which draws a bifurcation diagram. My code is as follows:

```
function bifur(x0,y0,a=1.3,b=0.4,n=1000,m=10000)
    i,x,y=1,x0,y0
    while i < n && abs(x) < m
        x,y = a - x^2 + y, b * x
        i += 1
    end
    if abs(x) < m
        return x
    else
        return 1000
    end
end
la = Float64[];
lx = Float64[];
for a=0:400
    for j = 1:1000
        x0 = rand()
        y0 = rand()
        x = bifur(x0,y0,a/100)
        if x != 1000
            push!(la,a/100) 
            push!(lx,x)
        end
    end
end
using Gadfly
myplot = Gadfly.plot( x=la, y=lx , Scale.x_discrete, Scale.y_continuous, Geom.point)
draw(PNG("myplot.png",10inch,8inch),myplot)
```

The output I get is this image:
[image]

In order to make my plot look more like this:
[image]
I need to be able to set point sizes to as small as one pixel. Then by increasing the iteration length I should be able to get a better bifurcation diagram. Does anyone know how to set the point sizes in Gadfly diagrams in Julia?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `default_point_size` in the [Theme](http://gadflyjl.org/themes.html) defaults?

Comment: Also do you know how to set the plot range by hand?

Comment: Have a look at the [Scale params](http://gadflyjl.org/scale_y_continuous.html).  Also wondering if you can set `ymin` and/or `ymax`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Just to encapsulate the comments as an answer...]

Gadfly's [Theme](https://gadflyjl.org/stable/man/themes) defaults can be changed.  In particular, `point_size` is probably what you are looking for.

For changing the automatic plot scale/range settings, have a look at Gadfly's [Scale params](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/lib/scales/#Gadfly.Scale.y_continuous).

Comment: @Cokes: Thanks!  Links are fixed now.

Comment: Links are broken again and I think Gadfly has changed some of these options. http://gadflyjl.org/stable/man/themes/

Comment: @Ali I've marked the answer as "community wiki".  Please feel free to update this answer or to provide a new one.  I'm not currently using Gadfly.

Answer (score 1):

If changing Theme values seems like too much, you can do it in the `plot` call directly. You need to provide an array of the same size as your x and y.

```
using Gadfly

x = rand(10)
y = rand(10)

p = plot(x=x, y=y, size=fill(2px, length(x)))
```